# Improve performance of SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a slow performing query which I am at a loss on how I could make more efficient. SQL isn't my speciality, but currently this query is taking about 3 seconds on average to run. I've run an execution plan on it in SMMS, and it recommended an index which I created. 3 seconds isn't awful currently, however I only have my own test data in (about 9,000 transactions, 22,000 transfers...). When I have a lot more people using this this will grow massively, and I don't want the execution time for this query to balloon substantially...

The intention of the query, is to return any transfers (and some information on their related transaction), which are of either type 0 or 1, which do not have a price stored for them in token prices (a price stored for anything within 3 hours would be a match, outside of 3 hours isn't a match - its 3 hours either side), where the number of attempts stored in the TokenPriceAttempts table is either 0, or <5 AND most recent is at least a week ago. tl;dr: return transfers, type 0 or 1, which don't have a price yet, and haven't had a recent (within the last week) attempt stored, or have no recent attempts, and have fewer than 5 total attempts.

Here is my query:

```
    SELECT
        [t1].[Id],
        [t1].[TransactionId],
        [t1].[From],
        [t1].[To],
        [t1].[Value],
        [t1].[Type],
        [t1].[ContractAddress],
        [t1].[TokenId],
        [t2].[Hash],
        [t2].[Timestamp]
    FROM
        -- Now, this pre-query is left-joined to token price attempts
        -- so ALL Transfers of type < 2 are considered
        (
            SELECT
                [t1].[Id],
                coalesce( COUNT([tpa].[Created]), 0 ) [Attempts],
                MAX([tpa].[Created]) [MaxCreated]
            FROM
                [dbo].[Transfers] [t1]
                LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TokenPriceAttempts] [tpa]
                    ON [t1].[Id] = [tpa].[TransferId]
            WHERE
                [t1].[Type] < 2
            GROUP BY
                [t1].[Id]
        ) [PQ]
    -- Now, we can just directly join to transfers for the rest
    JOIN [dbo].[Transfers] [t1]
        ON [PQ].[Id] = [t1].[Id]
        -- and the rest from the WITH CTE construct
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Transactions] [t2]
        ON [t1].[TransactionId] = [t2].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TokenPrices] [tp]
        ON [t1].[ContractAddress] = [tp].[ContractAddress]
            AND [tp].[Timestamp] >= DATEADD(HOUR, - 3, [t2].[Timestamp])
            AND [tp].[Timestamp] <= DATEADD(HOUR, 3, [t2].[Timestamp])
    WHERE
        ABS( DATEDIFF( SECOND, [tp].[Timestamp], [t2].[Timestamp] )) IS NULL
        AND
        (
            [PQ].[Attempts] = 0
            OR
            (
                [PQ].[Attempts] < 5
                AND DATEDIFF(DAY, [PQ].[MaxCreated], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) >= 7
            )
        )
```

And my execution plan (Not sure the best way to post this?):
EDIT 1: There is a paste of the execution plan XML at the bottom.
[image]

Finally, each of the referenced tables...

dbo.Transfers

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transfers]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [TransactionId] INT NOT NULL,
    [From] NVARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
    [To] NVARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
    [Value] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    [ValueDecimals] INT NOT NULL,
    [Type] TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [ContractAddress] NVARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
    [TokenId] NVARCHAR(256) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Transfers_Transactions] FOREIGN KEY ([TransactionId]) REFERENCES [Transactions]([Id])
)

GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_Transfers_Type] ON [dbo].[Transfers] ([Type])
```

dbo.TokenPriceAttempts

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TokenPriceAttempts]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [TransferId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Created] DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TokenPriceAttempts_Transfers] FOREIGN KEY ([TransferId]) REFERENCES [Transfers]([Id])
)
```

dbo.Transactions

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [Hash] NVARCHAR(66) NOT NULL,
    [BlockNumber] INT NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    [From] NVARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
    [To] NVARCHAR(42) NULL,
    [GasPaid] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Transactions_Hash] UNIQUE ([Hash])
)

GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_Transactions_BlockNumber] ON [dbo].[Transactions] ([BlockNumber])
```

dbo.TokenPrices

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TokenPrices]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [ContractAddress] NVARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    [PriceEth] DECIMAL(38,18) NOT NULL,
    [PriceUsd] DECIMAL(38,18) NOT NULL,
    [PriceGbp] DECIMAL(38,18) NOT NULL,
    [PriceEur] DECIMAL(38,18) NOT NULL,
    [PriceCad] DECIMAL(38,18) NOT NULL,
    [PriceAud] DECIMAL(38,18) NOT NULL,
    [PriceJpy] DECIMAL(38,18) NOT NULL,
    [PriceNzd] DECIMAL(38,18) NOT NULL,
    [PriceSgd] DECIMAL(38,18) NOT NULL,
    [PriceNok] DECIMAL(38,18) NOT NULL,
    [PriceSek] DECIMAL(38,18) NOT NULL,
    [PriceZar] DECIMAL(38,18) NOT NULL,
    [Created] DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)

--CA - CAD - Canada
--US - USD - United States
--AU - AUD - Australia
--JP - JPY - Japan
--NZ - NZD - New Zealand
--SG - SGD - Singapore
--AT - EUR - Austria
--BE - EUR - Belgium
--DE - EUR - Germany
--FI - EUR - Finland
--FR - EUR - France
--GR - EUR - Greece
--IT - EUR - Italy
--NL - EUR - Netherlands
--NO - NOK - Norway
--PT - EUR - Portugal
--ES - EUR - Spain
--CH - SEK - Switzerland
--GB - GBP - United Kingdom
--ZA - ZAR - South Africa
```

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the plan XML: https://pastebin.pl/view/d82f6aef

[**PasteThePlan here**](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkrSMOL85)

EDIT 2:
So I think based on the comments I have gotten a little performance back - Thank you. I am currently looking at the following query:

```
    SELECT
        [t1].[Id],
        [t1].[TransactionId],
        [t1].[From],
        [t1].[To],
        [t1].[Value],
        [t1].[Type],
        [t1].[ContractAddress],
        [t1].[TokenId],
        [t2].[Hash],
        [t2].[Timestamp],
        [PQ].[Attempts],
        [PQ].[MaxCreated]
    FROM
        -- Now, this pre-query is left-joined to token price attempts
        -- so ALL Transfers of type < 2 are considered
        (
            SELECT
                [t1].[Id],
                coalesce( COUNT([tpa].[Created]), 0 ) [Attempts],
                MAX([tpa].[Created]) [MaxCreated]
            FROM
                [dbo].[Transfers] [t1]
                LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TokenPriceAttempts] [tpa]
                    ON [t1].[Id] = [tpa].[TransferId]
            WHERE
                [t1].[Type] < 2
            GROUP BY
                [t1].[Id]
        ) [PQ]
    -- Now, we can just directly join to transfers for the rest
    JOIN [dbo].[Transfers] [t1]
        ON [PQ].[Id] = [t1].[Id]
        -- and the rest from the WITH CTE construct
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Transactions] [t2]
        ON [t1].[TransactionId] = [t2].[Id]
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM [dbo].[TokenPrices] [tp]
            WHERE
                [t1].[ContractAddress] = [tp].[ContractAddress]
                AND [tp].[Timestamp] >= DATEADD(HOUR, - 3, [t2].[Timestamp])
                AND [tp].[Timestamp] <= DATEADD(HOUR, 3, [t2].[Timestamp])
        )
        AND
        (
            [PQ].[Attempts] = 0
            OR
            (
                [PQ].[Attempts] < 5
                AND DATEDIFF(DAY, [PQ].[MaxCreated], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) >= 7
            )
        )
```

Its taking around a second now. Much better than before, but wonder if there's any more improvements I can make? I have tried looking at all comments and feel like there's more there that I could do, I just am at a loss. Have tried moving the final part of the final WHERE clause up inside the [PQ], but I had to put it as a HAVING clause there and the end result was such that it was a little slower than it currently is.

Also, new execution plan:
[image]
Was again unable to successfully upload the XML, for some reason, sorry. So have another paste here: https://pastebin.pl/view/f268d663

Comment: [Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) is a good place to share execution plans

Comment: @HoneyBadger Thanks, have tried pasting in the XML there but keep getting an error telling me it was unable to parse the XML... Not really sure why.

Comment: Paste the Plan has been a little "buggy" recently with new plans, can you post it in a Paste Bin, @pingu2k4 ?

Comment: In the first line of your XML, remove the `Version` and `Build` attributes on the first line before uploading

Comment: That `WHERE` makes no sense: it uses `ABS( DATEDIFF( SECOND, [tp].[Timestamp], [t2].[Timestamp] )) IS NULL` which is kind of pointless, you may as well say `([tp].[Timestamp] IS NULL OR [t2].[Timestamp] IS NULL)` which leads me to believe that you really want a `NOT EXISTS` not a `LEFT JOIN`. Also `COALESCE` is unnecessary on `COUNT` and it looks like the pre-grouped aggregation could be replaced with window functions. The main issue seems to be poor indexing.

Comment: Have added a paste of the execution plan XML. I had similar thoughts recently about the ABS(...) null check @Charlieface, however was unable to come up with something better. Everything else I tried wasn't working. Do you think something like this would be better? It seems faster but I can't be certain the results are identical yet, haven't tested fully. https://imgur.com/a/25qI6Th

Comment: Sometimes SSMS's Show Actual Execution Plan recommends a second index after you implement the first, for what it's worth. Also, plans for large tables can be quite different from plans from medium-size tables.

Comment: After I added the index it first suggested, I did run it again and saw no further index suggestions.

Comment: You have several alternative conditions you want your resultset's rows to fulfill. You might consider writing subqueries, as efficiently as possible, to get each condition's resultset separately, then take the UNION of those subqueries. Optimize each of the UNIONed subqueries separately.

Comment: Thanks for the comments from everyone. Have been able to save a little time so far I believe. I feel like I am still missing something, and everything else that I tried either ended up being slower, or wouldn't return what I needed etc. I have updated the original question with a new query at the bottom (labelled edit 2) and a new execution plan to match.